# How much time has passed between The Avengers and Iron Man 3?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3, the-avengers-2012

In The Avengers, Tony Stark debuts his latest and greatest armor: [the Mark VII](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_armor_%28Mark_VII%29).

While it is not entirely conclusive, people in New York are wearing light dress during the Avengers, so we can reasonably assume that the movie takes place somewhere between Spring to early Fall.

Iron Man 3 picks up an undisclosed amount of time later. Tony is wracked with a sort of PTSD and in his sleepless nights, has upped his armor collection all the way up to [Mark XLII](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_armor_%28Mark_XLII%29) - that's 35 new armors.

Christmas takes place over the course of the film - but of what year?

Comment: Not a full answer, but it's established that Iron Man 3 takes place during Christmas, albeit a Southern California snow-less Christmas, for the most part. I don't know if it's supposed to be the first Christmas after The Avengers or not.

Comment: Ah, yes - I forgot about the giant Christmas gift. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

During the scene of the café with Rhodes, I think the narration (Tony Stark voice) says something like "It's been six months since New-York and I am still having bad dreams" (or maybe it was one of the two who says it directly ?).

I'll edit if I find a source, but I recall six months being mentioned at some point.

Comment: I'm also sure that a similar time frame was mentioned in that scene (though I thought it was part of the dialogue between the two rather than narration). Unfortunately I can't find a source for it.

Comment: makes sense.  tony stark seems like the kind of guy that would do nothing but develop new/better tech if he was unable to sleep.

Comment: He also built the original Mark I within a few days (or a week) with basically no resources. Now with Jarvis running the automated manufacturing process Tony can just whip up new designs and have the machines build them.

Comment: It's also probable that some of the later suits where developed simultaneously as they have a similar framework to go off.  The Mark XLII is the first real deviation from the general structure of the other platforms with its prehensile nature.

Comment: He mentions 6 months in one of the trailers which I guess pulls dialogue from that scene.